# How to create multiple texts with seperator android

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nwDf.jpg)

As in this picture, (in the right), location, name, distance type of place and between all those 4, there is a seperator like `----------------`

And all those lines are clickable. When one line clicked , it goes to that four item information screen.

How can i do?

Comment: Are you using ListView or RecyclerView?

Comment: ListView. Also i need scrolling. So scrollview maybe i want to migrate.

Answer (score 1):

ListView has built-in dividers. You can control their appearance using the `android:divider` and `android:dividerHeight` attributes. The former allows you to specify a color or drawable to use as the divider.

Comment: but i will create dynamically?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I will create 5 arraylists (namelocationtime etc) in asynctask and in postexecute, i want to push them to screen like in the picture. I dont know how many i will retrieve, so i will create textviews dynamically. I have only a layout linear to put those.